# Как происходит удаление элемента из списка в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть вот такой кусок кода

```
import random

A = float(input("Введите А: "))
B = float(input("Введите В: "))
List = []
List2 = []

for i in range(0, 31):
    List.append(random.randint(A, B))


List2 = List
List2.pop(0)


print(List)

print(List2)
```

При выполнении получаю примерно следующее:

```
Введите А: 10
Введите В: 20
[13, 12, 10, 16, 13, 20, 11, 11, 11, 12, 10, 12, 15, 13, 18, 18, 13, 14, 12, 13, 20, 15, 16, 19, 12, 10, 18, 14, 18, 20]
[13, 12, 10, 16, 13, 20, 11, 11, 11, 12, 10, 12, 15, 13, 18, 18, 13, 14, 12, 13, 20, 15, 16, 19, 12, 10, 18, 14, 18, 20]
```

То есть элемент из списка не удаляется. Но если написать вот так:

```
import random

A = float(input("Введите А: "))
B = float(input("Введите В: "))
List = []
List2 = []

for i in range(0, 31):
    List.append(random.randint(A, B))


print(List)

List2 = List
List2.pop(0)

print(List2)
```

то результат получается такой, какой и ожидается:

```
Введите А: 10
Введите В: 20
[18, 15, 15, 12, 19, 17, 13, 19, 16, 15, 18, 17, 10, 19, 17, 15, 15, 14, 10, 15, 17, 10, 14, 17, 20, 11, 12, 11, 12, 19, 20]
[15, 15, 12, 19, 17, 13, 19, 16, 15, 18, 17, 10, 19, 17, 15, 15, 14, 10, 15, 17, 10, 14, 17, 20, 11, 12, 11, 12, 19, 20]
```

Почему это отрабатывает так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: обратите внимание на длину итоговых списков в вашем первом примере

Answer (score 1):

Новый код:

```
import random

A = float(input("Введите А: "))
B = float(input("Введите В: "))
List = []
List2 = []

for i in range(31):
    List.append(random.randint(A, B))


List2 = List[:]
List2.pop(0)


print(List)

print(List2)
```

### Разберём ваши ошибки.

Во-первых, с помощью `List2=List` вы  ссылаетесь на список `List`, и при изменении `List2` у вас изменяется и `List` тоже.
То есть, вы неверно написали:

> То есть элемент из списка не удаляется.

Элемент удаляется, но удаляется из двух списков.
Соответственно, во втором случае если вы замените кусок кода:

```
print(List)

List2 = List
List2.pop(0)

print(List2)
```

на  следующий

```
print(List) #одно значение

List2 = List
List2.pop(0)
print(List) #совершенно другое значение
print(List2)
```

, то список `List` выведется двумя *разными* значениями.

Чтобы решить проблему, замените `List2=List` на `List2=List[:]` (как я уже сделал в готовом коде)

***Во-вторых, зачем делать*** `for i in range(0, 31)`***, если можно сделать*** `for i in range(31)`***?***

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы создаете не новую переменную, как это делается в других языках, а создаете новую ссылку на уже созданный объект.

Чтобы создать новый объект делается так:

```
import copy
List2 = copy.deepcopy(List)
```

Comment: Простите, это я уже написал

Comment: Зачем бессмысленно давать одинаковые ответы?

Comment: Где мой ответ одинаковый? Я автору объяснил до конца, в отличии от вас.

Comment: Ну я-то заменил в готовом коде! А вы пытаетесь рассказать то, что уже _было_ рассказано

Comment: Еще раз прочтите мой ответ, и найдите это в своем ответе.

Comment: Вот вам части: Потому что вы создаете не новую переменную, как это делается в других языках, а создаете новую ссылку на уже созданный объект (у Вас) - Во-первых, с помощью `List2=List` вы ссылаетесь на список List, и при изменении `List2` у вас изменяется и `List` тоже. То есть... (у меня);  Чтобы создать новый объект делается так... (у Вас) - Чтобы решить проблему, замените `List2=List `на `List2=List[:]` (как я уже сделал в готовом коде) (у меня)

Comment: И я скопировал ваш ответ?  Или я предложил автору альтернативный вариант?